# How can I put conversions into functions?

Tags: python

F = Temp_C * (9/5) +32

C =  (Temp_F-32) *(5/9)

Write 2 functions

1. c_to_f(ctemp)
2. f_to_c(ftemp)

These should convert from Celsius to Fahrenheit and  Fahrenheit  to Celsius 
Create a Loop that will print the following:

1. A table of temperatures from -50 F to 220 F and each number in between (counting by 10)
2. A table of temperatures from 0 C to 120 C and each number in between (counting by 10)For instance for number 1
   -50 F    -45.55 C
   -40 F    -40 C
   ....
   0 F    -17 C
   ...
   ...
   210 F    98.88 C
   220 F    104.44 C

Following is the answer but how can I put conversions into functions ?

```
for currentCelsiusTemperature in range (-55,220,10):
    FahrenheitTemperatureEquivalent = (9/5) * currentCelsiusTemperature + 32
    print(currentCelsiusTemperature,"\t", FahrenheitTemperatureEquivalent)


for currentCelsiusTemperature in range (0,120,10):
    FahrenheitTemperatureEquivalent = (9/5) * currentCelsiusTemperature + 32
    print(currentCelsiusTemperature,"\t", FahrenheitTemperatureEquivalent)
```

Comment: Well, what have you tried to do? What resources have you viewed to try to find out the answer?

Comment: 1. Unix-specific programming questions should be allowed (although this question is not). 2. Off-topic programming questions should be migrated to their according site (this time, SO).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With *Python* function definition:

```
def c_to_f(c_temp):
    return (9/5) * c_temp + 32

def f_to_c(f_temp):
    return (f_temp - 32) * (5/9)

for celcius_temp in range(-55, 220, 10):
    print('{} C\t{} F'.format(celcius_temp, c_to_f(celcius_temp)))
```

Sample output:

```
-55 C   -23 F
-45 C   -13 F
-35 C   -3 F
-25 C   7 F
-15 C   17 F
-5 C    27 F
5 C 37 F
15 C    47 F
25 C    57 F
35 C    67 F
45 C    77 F
55 C    87 F
65 C    97 F
75 C    107 F
85 C    117 F
95 C    127 F
105 C   137 F
115 C   147 F
125 C   157 F
135 C   167 F
145 C   177 F
155 C   187 F
165 C   197 F
175 C   207 F
185 C   217 F
195 C   227 F
205 C   237 F
215 C   247 F
```